# C# Dynamically call methods

Tags: c#

Is there a way to call methods at run time.?

I would like to store functions definitions as a string in text file and at run time i just want to read all text from that file and convert into function/method and pass parameter to that and get result.

ex :

```
int add_no (int a ,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

is that possible in C#??

Comment: Look up "c# reflection" and go from there.

Comment: No Boss!! I want to store full function in text file and read,convert to function,pass parameter and get result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/826435/5103294

Comment: This one even better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3188953/5103294

Comment: Note that for any of these the code has to be contained in a new class - you can's add methods to an _existing_ class.

Comment: See: [Can Roslyn be used to generate dynamic method similar to DynamicMethod IL generation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32096423/880990)

Comment: Why don't you give Roslyn a try?